# Remove all lines in file A which contain the strings in file B

Tags: linux, command-line, text-processing

I have a CSV file `users.csv` with a list of userNames, userIDs, and other data:

```
username, userid, sidebar_side, sidebar_colour
"John Lennon", 90123412, "left", "blue"
"Paul McCartny", 30923833, "left", "black"
"Ringo Starr", 77392318, "right", "blue"
"George Harrison", 72349482, "left", "green"
```

In another file `toremove.txt` I have a list of userIDs:

```
30923833
77392318
```

Is there a clever, efficient way to remove all the rows from the `users.csv` file which contain the IDs in `toremove.txt`? I have written a simple Python app to parse the two files and write to a new file only those lines that are not found in `toremove.txt`, but it is extraordinarily slow. Perhaps some `sed` or `awk` magic can help here?

This is the desired result, considering the examples above:

```
username, userid, sidebar_side, sidebar_colour
"John Lennon", 90123412, "left", "blue"
"George Harrison", 72349482, "left", "green"
```

Comment: Maybe you should share your python script. I suspect there's something wrong there, like being O(N²) Although if you are keeping and removing millions of records magic won't help too much.

Comment: The script is in fact O(n<sup>2</sup>): n for the `users.csv` file's lines, and n for the lines of `toremove.txt`. I'm not really sure how to do it with lower complexity. The gist of it is: `for u in users: if not any(toremove in u): outputfile.write(u)`. I can post it to Code Review.

Comment: I would read `toremove.txt`, saving the entries as *keys*. Iterate users.csv, printing those where the id is not in the dict. You get O(n) processing for both `toremove.txt` and `users.csv`, and O(n) memory usage for `toremove.txt` (which is probably relatively small)

Comment: @Ángel: Yes, that is exactly how the script works!

Comment: Checking if a key exists in a dictionary, equals to a  hash table check, which is (almost) O(1). On the other hand, if it needs to iterate the items to remove, that's O(m)

Comment: Thank you. So if I have two lists say `i` and `j`, and perform a `for` loop over `i` inside a for loop inside `j`, that is considered `O(n)` and not `O(n^2)`? I just assumed that the loop in the loop meant `O(n^2)`, from what I understand about [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: No. If you perform two loops (or use a builtin that internally has a loop) one inside the other, then it's O(n²) [or if you prefer to differenciate both lists, O(n·m)]. The trick is that if you store the items in a  hash table (and there are no collisions degrading its behavior) then you can perform lookups in O(1). Thus, you can perform the filterint in O(n+m) instead of O(n×m). In python you could use a set() or a dict().

Comment: Thank you! I am storing the items from `toremove.txt` in a list. I'll try a set instead and see how effective that is. In any case, I'll be sure to google hash table, python complexity for lists and sets, and filterint. For better or worse I'm a self-taught dev (learned Mechanical Engineering in university) so I've got a lot of holes to fill in. I really do appreciate your advice and your patience, Ángel.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With `grep`, you can do:

```
$ grep -vwF -f toremove.txt users.txt 
username, userid, sidebar_side, sidebar_colour
"John Lennon", 90123412, "left", "blue"
"George Harrison", 72349482, "left", "green"
```

With `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'[ ,]' 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next} !($4 in a)' toremove.txt users.txt 
username, userid, sidebar_side, sidebar_colour
"John Lennon", 90123412, "left", "blue"
"George Harrison", 72349482, "left", "green"
```

Comment: @terdon: Dang! I was going to say that. Note, though, that Gnouc’s answer (arguably) does what the question _asks for_, but it might not be what the user wants.

Comment: The `awk` solution is highly sensitive to the files’ being formatted _exactly_ as shown in the question. Most glaringly, if a name is just one word/token (i.e., it contains no spaces; e.g., `"Bono"`) or is more than two tokens (i.e., it contains more than one space; e.g., `"Sir Paul McCartney"`), it will go through even if the userid matches. Less obviously, the same thing happens if there is no space between the first comma and the userid, or if there is more than one space (e.g., `"John Lennon",  90123412, …`).

Comment: @Scott: Yes, it's the reason I put `awk` solution behind `grep`

Answer (score 4):

Here’s Gnouc’s `awk` answer, modified to be space-blind:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next} !(gensub("^ *","",1,$2) in a)' toremove.txt users.csv
```

Since it uses only commas (and not spaces) as delimiters,
`$1` is `"John Lennon"`, `$2` is  `90123412` (with a leading space), etc. 
So we use `gensub` to remove any number of leading spaces from `$2`
before we check whether it (the userid) was in the `toremove.txt` file.

Comment: You might be able to do some other clever stuff here (just thinking out loud) like parsing out the "exact piece" of the string that shouldn't match, and comparing that with the associative array, or what not.

Comment: I believe that's what I'm doing.  What did you have in mind?

Comment: Yes you are.  I was just referring to if you needed to do something more funky like removing the first half of a line or anything like that (downcasing, etc. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4784647/32453) just specialized parsing

Answer (score 0):

OK a ruby way: if you have a list of strings in a file, and you want to remove all lines from another file that even *contain* any string in the first file (in this case removing "file2" from "file1") ruby file:

```
b=File.read("file2").split # subtract this one out
remove_regex = Regexp.new(b.join('|'))
File.open("file1", "r").each_line do |line|
  if line !~ remove_regex
    puts line
  end
end
```

unfortunately with a large "to remove" file this seems to degrade complexity-wise to O(N^2) (my assumption is the regexp has a lot of work to do), but still might be useful to someone out there (if you want more than removing full lines).  It might be faster in certain cases.

Another option if you're going for speed is to use the same hash checking mechanism, but to carefully "parse" the line for strings that might match, then comparing them with your hash.

In ruby, might look like this:

```
b=File.read("file2").split # subtract this one out
hash={}
for line in b
  hash[line] = 1
end

ARGF.each_line do |line|
  ok = true
  for number in line.scan(/\d{9}/)
    if hash.key? number
      ok=false
    end
  end
  if (ok)
    puts line
  end
end
```

See also Scott's answer, its similar to the awk answers proposed hither thither, and avoids O(N^2) complexity (phew).