# Match and combine records in Bash

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, grep

Consider two csv files:

```
$ cat given.csv
123,John
246,Paul
369,George
987,Ringo

$ cat family.csv
246,McCartney
123,Lennon
987,Starr
369,Harrison
```

*Note that the lines are not ordered!* How might I use `awk`, `grep`, and other `bash` tools to get a combined output file (order unimportant):

```
123,John,Lennon
246,Paul,McCartney
369,George,Harrison
987,Ringo,Starr
```

I was thinking about running a `for` loop over the first file, then using `awk` to get the id and *then* grepping the second file for the relevant record. **Is there a more straightforward way to do this in Bash**? I find that often bash has [a clever, efficient way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145079/remove-all-lines-in-file-a-which-contain-the-strings-in-file-b) to handle text files that I'm not yet familiar with.

Comment: The answers in the link you give use `grep` resp. `awk`. That has nothing to do with `bash` apart from `bash` being one of an unendless number of programs from which you could do so.

Comment: Thank you Anthon. I don't mind the downvote if the question can be improved. Actually, I appreciate it so long as the downvoter mentions what needs improving! I mention bash as the `for` loop is done by Bash.

Comment: The simple joining of unordered files has been asked and answered before. The answer you selected doesn't work on CSV files in general, it just works for the restricted example you gave. The next person using more real CSV files going to find out the hard way. That makes the question not very useful.

Comment: I see, Anthon. I don't see this as a dup of the link that you posted as the input formats are completely different (the OP of that question is not taking data from the second file's rows), even if the `join` command does resolve both issues. I actually did do a comprehensive search before asking and was surprised that this question had not been asked before. My original worry would be that the answer would be in perl!

Comment: Why worry about that? Perl has a library  (as do Python, Ruby) that can **properly** handle CSV files, for which the `join` "solution" would give faulty results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**With join and sort:**

```
join -t , <(sort given.csv) <(sort family.csv)
```

Output:

```
123,John,Lennon
246,Paul,McCartney
369,George,Harrison
987,Ringo,Starr
```

---

**With grep:**

```
#!/bin/bash

F1="given.csv"
F2="family.csv"
D=","           # delimiter

while IFS="$D" read FIRST_COLUMN REST; do
  T="$FIRST_COLUMN$D$REST"
  T+="$(grep -oP "^$FIRST_COLUMN\K$D.*" "$F2")" && echo "$T"
done < "$F1"
```

Output:

```
123,John,Lennon
246,Paul,McCartney
369,George,Harrison
987,Ringo,Starr
```

Comment: Thank you. **The `join` command is perfect!** Note that the bash breaks if lines are found in the `given.csv` file that have no match in the `last.csv` file, though that requirement was not specified in the OP. No mind that, answer accepted!

Comment: Thanks for the note. Now I've fixed this bug in my bash/grep version.