# Remove all rows in a CSV file without corresponding/matching timestamp in another CSV file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, csv, macos

I have 2 CSV files which look like follows:

**`file1.csv`**

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,date,time,col7
1,2,3,4,2019-07-20,12:40:00,0
1,2,3,4,2019-07-20,12:43:00,0
1,2,3,4,2019-07-20,12:44:00,0
1,2,3,4,2019-07-20,12:45:00,0
1,2,3,4,2019-07-20,12:46:00,0
1,2,3,4,2019-07-20,12:47:00,0
```

**`file2.csv`**

```
date,time,col3
2019-07-20,12:40:00,1
2019-07-20,12:41:00,2
2019-07-20,12:42:00,3
2019-07-20,12:43:00,4
2019-07-20,12:44:00,5
2019-07-20,12:45:00,6
2019-07-20,12:46:00,7
2019-07-20,12:47:00,8
```

As one can see in `file2.csv`, for for rows 2 and 3 with timestamps `2019-07-20,12:41:00` and `2019-07-20,12:42:00` respectively, no corresponding rows exist with the same timestamp in `file1.csv`. I would like to output `file2.csv` with those specific rows removed so that only rows with matching timestamps in `file1.csv` will remain.

Is it possible to perform this with a simple command in command line? I have a hunch it might involve regex matching but I am not sure about the most efficient way to perform this operation.

Thank you!

Comment: An Awk script can be easily adapted from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145081. If you haven't seen Awk before, you may like [this simple Awk tutorial](https://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~dholland/computers/awk.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$5 FS $6]; next} ($1 FS $2) in a' file1 file2  
date,time,col3
2019-07-20,12:40:00,1
2019-07-20,12:43:00,4
2019-07-20,12:44:00,5
2019-07-20,12:45:00,6
2019-07-20,12:46:00,7
2019-07-20,12:47:00,8
```

Comment: @thanasisp why would `a[$5 FS $6]` be any different than `a[$5$6]`? And surely `FS` isn't the right choice! `FS` can be an expression. Did you mean `OFS`?

Comment: FS is the right choice, because it cannot exist into a field after splitting. OFS would be good if we had set it first here, now it is space and FS is comma. The reason is demonstrated by this example pair `test1,test2` and `test1t,est2` both fields compinations would have the same `$1$2`.

Comment: @thanasisp ah! Yes indeed, I see. I still don't think using `FS` is a good idea though. Consider cases where `FS` is `[a : *]` or any other character class. It's absolutely the right thing here, but not in more complex cases.

Comment: @thanasisp yes, that does make sense. Good suggestion, thanks!

Comment: What speaks against the `awk` standard mechanism of "fake" two-dimensional arrays, which uses a special character stored in `SUBSEP` (by default `0x1c`). You could then use `a[$5,$6]` for two-dimensional arrays even without GNU awk (btw, AFAIK this means that `$5,$6` as array index will NOT concatenate using `FS`),.

Comment: Thank you, this worked beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

```
csv-sqlite -i file1.csv -i file2.csv \
  'select * from input2 where date || time in (select date || time from input1) |
  csv-header --remove-types'
```

csv-sqlite is from [csv-nix-tools](https://github.com/mslusarz/csv-nix-tools).